# How can I modify elements in one list conditional on the elements in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists. The elements in the first list correspond to elements in the second list. I want to combine all elements in listA that have 'name' as consecutive tags, and reflect the changes in listB.

example input:

```
listA = ['my','name','is','dumbledore',',','albus','dumbledore','.','they','call','me','albus','percival','wulfric','brian','dumbledore','.']
listB = ['x','x','x,'name','x','name','name','x','x','x','x','name','name','name','name','name','x']
```

expected output:

```
listA = ['my','name','is','dumbledore',',','albus_dumbledore','.','they','call','me','albus_percival_wulfric_brian_dumbledore','.']
listB = ['x','x','x','name','x','name','x','x','x','x','name','x']
```

So far, this is what I have:

```
prev_a = None
prev_b = None
i=-1
for a, b in zip(listA, listB):
    i += 1
    places = 0
    if b == 'name':
        if prev_b == b:
            prev_a = prev_a + '_' + a
            del listB[i]
            listA[i-1] = prev_a
            del listA[i]
    prev_a = a
    prev_b = b

print(listA)
print(listB)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
['my', 'name', 'is', 'dumbledore', ',', 'albus_dumbledore', '.', 'they', 'call', 'me', 'albus_percival', 'percival_brian', 'dumbledore', '.']
['x', 'x', 'x', 'name', 'x', 'name', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'name', 'name', 'name', 'x']
```

This is not correct. How can I generalize this to work for names longer than 2 words without knowing in advance the length of the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the names until you reach a none name then add it to the result.

```
resA = []
resB = []
current = None
for a,b in zip(listA,listB):
    if b == 'x':
        if current:
            resA.append(current)
            resB.append('name')
            current = None
        resA.append(a)
        resB.append(b)
    else:
        current= current + '_'+a if current else a

if current:
        resA.append(current)
        resB.append('name')


print(resA)
print(resB)
```

yields:

```
['my', 'name', 'is', 'dumbledore', ',', 'albus_dumbledore', '.', 'they', 'call', 'me', 'albus_percival_wulfric_brian_dumbledore', '.']
['x', 'x', 'x', 'name', 'x', 'name', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'name', 'x']
```